# Is there a list anywhere of humanoid undead?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, undead, human

I'm trying to build an undead sea witch. She is the main bad guy for my current campaign.  She was a pirate captain who's entire set of islands were destroyed by an leviathan (it's complicated) followed by 6 years of constant hurricane like storms. She was saved from drowning by making a bargain with something from what is basically a combo of hell and the abyss. The patron made her undead (she wanted to 'survive and wreak her vengeance' so technically, he gave her what she wanted). I'm having trouble narrowing down what kind of undead she is. (or something close I can tweak). But I can find humanoid lists and undead lists, but no list I can sort by both categories without looking through every undead on the d20psrd site.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you looking for creatures that have both the undead type and the humanoid (sub)type, or just undead creatures that typically have a roughly-humanoid appearance? ... that is, should the [zombie](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/zombie/) be included?

Comment: Right on d20pfsrd: https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/tools/monster-filter/.  The various search/filter tools aren't well linked, but they do exist at the very bottom of the menu.